# Lastest updates for my X25-M 80 GB intel disc?

Tags: ssd, firmware, intel-x25-m

How can I make sure I have the lastest updates and firmware to my X25-M 80 GB SSD disc? I know a few updates has been released but I'm not sure on how to check for updates and what's installed for my my disc.

Answer (score 1):

[This](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Solid+State+Drives+and+Caching&ProductLine=Intel%C2%AE+High+Performance+Solid+State+Drive&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE+X25-M+Solid+State+Drive%2c+80GB+SATA+II+2.5in%2c+MLC%2c+High+Performance) looks like a good place to start.